# TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.db.collection is not a function

Tags: firebase, next.js

So I was watching this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBotWYKYYWc&list=PLf16UKl7nR5AjcrYOe1niifJSAls3spDk&index=9) and at around 3:03:00, I got stuck and got the above error.

Here is the code for *firebase.js*

```js
    import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
    import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL, uploadString } from 'firebase/storage';
    import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';


    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxx"
      };

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getFirestore(app);
    const storage = getStorage(app);

    export { app, db, storage, collection, addDoc, serverTimestamp, ref, getDownloadURL, 
    uploadString };
```

In *inputBox.js file*, the following code is included.

```js
    import { db, collection, storage, addDoc, serverTimestamp, ref, getDownloadURL, uploadString  } from '../firebase'

    const sendPost = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    
      if (!inputRef.current.value) return;
    
      addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
        message: inputRef.current.value,
        name: session.user.name,
        email: session.user.email,
        image: session.user.image,
        timestamp: serverTimestamp()
      })
        .then((docRef) => {
          if (imageToPost) {
            const uploadTask = uploadString(ref(storage, `posts/${docRef.id}`), imageToPost, 'data_url');
    
            removeImage();
    
            uploadTask.on('state_changed',
              null,
              (error) => {
                console.error(error);
              },
              () => {
                getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `posts/${docRef.id}`))
                  .then((downloadURL) => {
                    return updateDoc(doc(db, 'posts', docRef.id), {
                      postImage: downloadURL
                    });
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                  });
              }
            );
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    
      inputRef.current.value = '';
    };
```

In *Posts.js file*, the following code is included.

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';
    import { db } from '../firebase';
    import Post from './Post';
    
    const Posts = () => {
      const postsRef = db.collection('posts').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc');
      const [realtimePosts, loading, error] = useCollectionData(postsRef, { idField: 'id' });
    
      if (loading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
      }
    
      if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          {realtimePosts.map((post) => (
            <Post
              key={post.id}
              name={post.name}
              message={post.message}
              email={post.email}
              timestamp={post.timestamp}
              image={post.image}
              postImage={post.postImage}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Posts;
```

I am wondering what went wrong although I tried to update the code to the latest version I think. I would like to solve this error.

`TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.db.collection is not a function.`

which occurred in the *Posts.js file.*

Comment: Hi saddysad, please provide more information on what you are trying to do as it is not reasonable to expect people to watch the video to help you with your issue.

Comment: @Stf_F I am sorry. I thought that was enough information. About the video, I didn't mean for people to watch the video to help me with the issue. It was attached for the reference.  I tried solving this issue using Chatgpt and it is finally working now. Thank you.